# Sorting multidimentional array by its value and size

Tags: php

I have this array. I have used usort and able to do alphabetical order but I need to sort based on sizing too. please see the below sample example and the expected output. any suggestion

```
[
   0 => ['b','a','n','a','n','a'],
   1 => ['a','n','a','n','a'],
   2 => ['n','a','n','a'],
   3 => ['a','n','a'],
   4 => ['n','a'],
   5 => ['a']
]
```

Need sorting like below:

```
[
   0 => ['a'],
   1 => ['a','n','a'],
   2 => ['a','n','a','n','a'],
   3 => ['b','a','n','a','n','a'],
   4 => ['n','a'],
   5 => ['n','a','n','a']
]
```

Comment: What if you have two entries a,n,a and a,a,n?

Comment: @NigelRen sort by name may be? a,a,n first. Then a,n,a?

Answer (score 1):

Sort them as strings

```
usort($arr, function($a,$b) { return strcmp(implode('', $a), implode('', $b)); });
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1d28b115772ff4da3f3f3a57514d01fde00ec6dd)